# Spivak's Calculus - don't understand lemma for theorem of limit laws

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So, I've been going through Spivak's Calculus (Chapter 5, Limits). I am currently stuck on the proof for Theorem 2 (p. 103) illustrating the limit laws (Sum Rule, Product Rule). I do not quite understand how the values for $\delta$ are determined in the lemma as such:

Lemma (2): If

$$|x - x_0| < \min \left(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}\right) \\
|y - y_0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1},
$$

then

$$|xy - x_0y_0| < \varepsilon$$

This is followed by the proof:

(2) Since $|x-x_0| < 1$ we have

$$|x| - |x_0| \le |x - x_0| < 1, $$

so that
$$ |x| < 1 + |x_0|$$

thus
$$ 
|xy - x_0y_0| = |x(y-y_0) + y_0(x-x_0)| \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \ \ \le |x| \cdot |y-y_0| + |y_0| \cdot |x-x_0| \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \ \ \lt (1 + |x_0|) \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)} + |y_0| \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)} \\
\lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon \ \ \
$$

Two things I mainly do not understand:

1. How is the term $\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)}$ derived? (there was a section earlier on deriving a similar term, but that was for an example on resolving $\lim_{x \to a} x^2.$ and obtaining $\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|a| + 1)}$ in the process).
2. Why is it that the term $|y_0| \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}$ equates to $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$?

Comment: 1. That's just a number that happens to work.

Comment: @AnginaSeng by 'happens to work', did you mean it just happens to allow the proof to formulate the final inequality nicely?

Comment: Indeed it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically just need a number for $\delta$ that is positive and can be used to manipulate $|xy-x_0 y_0|$ to be less than any $\epsilon$. So, since they obtained
$|x| |y-y_0| + |y_0| |x-x_0|$ from the triangle inequality, they decided to somehow make the two summands both less than $\epsilon/2$ to get the desired result. The easiest way was to have $|y-y_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$ since that is definitely positive and definitely an easy way to help force it to become less than $\epsilon/2$, along with using the inequality defined for $|x-x_0|$.

Comment: Hmm.. sure, I can accept that it makes it nicer for algebraic manipulation. I am just confused as to how I would come up with such terms when devising my own proof since I have no mental model as to how to manipulate it to that point.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not much to say because many other terms could be good with same reasoning, e.g. every number $\frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+s)} $ with $s > 1$, but if you choose $s>1$ then you will have a 'weaker' if statement because  $
     \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+s)} < \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)} $

2. there is no equality , but anyway the inequality is valid (consider that $ \frac{|y_0|}{ |y_0|+1} < 1$)

Comment: AHHHHH that struck me for 2. Thank you!!!